# Json from C# to JAVA

Tags: java, json

I have a web application in C#, and I use JsonSerializer to create a json.
Now I'm wotrking on an android application and I'm trying to read the json.

On my Android application, my code is

```
try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            client.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT, "android");
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            request.setURI(new URI(uri));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String line = "";
            String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                sb.append(line + NL);
            }
            in.close();
            String page = sb.toString();


            JSONObject  jsonObject = new JSONObject(page);   // here it explodes
}
```

It get explodes when trying to create a json object, because the value of "page"  is

```
"{\\"Key\\":\\"1\\",\\"RowVersion\\":[0,0,0,0,0,0,226,148].....
```

When I try to get the json on the browser manually (with direct GET url), I get

```
"{\"Key\":\"1\",\"RowVersion\":[0,0,0,0,0,0,226,148]......
```

When I copy this string manually it works fine.

How can I fix it?

Comment: side note, not related to question: use `StringBuilder`, not `StringBuffer`

Comment: Hold on, do you actually get the content you say from the direct URL, or is that a string you made up out of the content you get? If what you show is the original content, there is clearly a bug on the C# side

Comment: why? I have a method on C# application that return a string.. I want to access this string for my mobile app.

Comment: But what you get from the URL is a string, IT IS NOT A JSON OBJECT. You are in fact returned the JSON object as a string...

Comment: @fge thanks, I fixed it on C# side to return a json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returned a JSON object as a String whereas you expected a JSON object...

With Jackson, this is easily solved:

```
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
// JSON object as a string...
final JsonNode malformed = mapper.readTree(response.getEntity().getContent());
// To JSON object
final JsonNode OK = mapper.readTree(malformed.textValue());
```

Either this, or fix the server side so as to return the JSON object!

Comment: How can I return a JSON from a controller in C#? all I find are methods to return strings

Comment: I have no idea, since I don't know what you use on the C# side. If you can't fix it, use Jackson as shown above and you'll be done with it. Side note: it is MUCH more powerful than Android's builtin JSON library.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your code it too complicated, try do it like this:

```
String page = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```